# Using json on php

Tags: php, json, foreach

I don't have any idea how to call this, but I'm going to be simple on explaining.
English isn't my native language so it's so hard for me, but I'm trying.

I have a json page with data that I would like to show on my page using foreach. 
The json data looks like thi :

```
    [{
"seller": "hashim",
"sa": "10",
"name": "Kuzhina"
},
{
"seller": "kadri",
"sa": "1",
"name": "Majmuna"
},
{
"seller": "mood",
"sa": "4",
"name": "Karrika"
},
{
"seller": "muslim",
"sa": "1",
"name": "Xhama"
},
{
"seller": "muslim",
"sa": "15",
"name": "Kauqa"
},
{
"seller": "lule",
"sa": "2",
"name": "Stringa"
},
{
"seller": "huder",
"sa": "465",
"name": "Kreveta"
},
{
"seller": "Majmun",
"sa": "1",
"name": "Dollapa"
},
{
"seller": "muslim",
"sa": "680",
"name": "Historiku"
},
{
"seller": "muslim",
"sa": "1",
"name": "Netflix"
}
```

On my page I want to show text like this :

Seller, hashim has added 10 Kuzhina in the last 24 hours.

Seller, muslim has added 1 Xhama, 15 Kauqa, 680 Historiku, 1 Netflix in the last 24 hours.

How can I do this?

I hope that you understood me.

Comment: `json_decode()` then loop

Comment: Yes I did that, but as you can see from json_data some sellers are shown double times with different name. 
I would like the format to be like this. 

`Seller, muslim has added 1 Xhama, 15 Kauqa, 680 Historiku, 1 Netflix in the last 24 hours.

Seller, (seller) has added (sa) (name), (sa) (name), (sa) (name) in the last 24 hours. `
When I do json_decode and loop it shows like this : 

`Seller, muslim has added 1 Xhama in the last 24 hours. 

Seller, muslim has added 15 kauqa in the last 24 hours. 

...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_decode` to create a unique array of sellers, and then loop through both the array of sellers and the data, as follows:

```
$json = '[{
"seller": "hashim",
"sa": "10",
"name": "Kuzhina"
},
{
"seller": "kadri",
"sa": "1",
"name": "Majmuna"
},
{
"seller": "mood",
"sa": "4",
"name": "Karrika"
},
{
"seller": "muslim",
"sa": "1",
"name": "Xhama"
},
{
"seller": "muslim",
"sa": "15",
"name": "Kauqa"
},
{
"seller": "lule",
"sa": "2",
"name": "Stringa"
},
{
"seller": "huder",
"sa": "465",
"name": "Kreveta"
},
{
"seller": "Majmun",
"sa": "1",
"name": "Dollapa"
},
{
"seller": "muslim",
"sa": "680",
"name": "Historiku"
},
{
"seller": "muslim",
"sa": "1",
"name": "Netflix"
}]';

$data = json_decode($json);
/* store unique sellers names in an array: */
$arr_sellers = [];
foreach($data as $v){ if(!in_array($v->seller, $arr_sellers)){ $arr_sellers[] = $v->seller; }}

/* Loop through both the array of sellers and data: */
foreach($arr_sellers as $seller){
$str = '';
foreach($data as $v){ if($v->seller == $seller){$str .= $v->sa .' '.$v->name.', '; }}
$str = trim($str,', ');
echo 'Seller, '. $seller.' has added '.$str.' in the last 24 hours';
echo '<br/>';}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this. Decode first then foreach loop on with echo.

```
$record = json_decode($json);
foreach ($record as $info){
    echo 'Seller, ' . $info->seller . ' has added ' . $info->sa . ' '
     . $info->name . 'in the last 24 hours.<br>';
};
```

Comment: code not tested but it should help you work around. :)

Comment: Yes I tried that but as I said the loop goes like this 
`Seller, muslim has added 1 Xhama in the last 24 hours. 
Seller, muslim has added 15 kauqa in the last 24 hours. ...`

I want it to go like this 
`Seller, muslim has added 1 Xhama, 15 Kauqa, 680 Historiku, 1 Netflix in the last 24 hours.`